# Efficiently retrieiving indices from lattice with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: c++

This is something I've never thought too much about because it seemed like an unnecessary micro-optimization, but I've come across a situation where this computation is actually the primary bottleneck in my code, so I figure it is worth it to think about whether this can be improved.

I'm simulating a model on a 3D cubic lattice with length $L$ in each direction. A site has a unique index $0 \leq i < L^3$ given by the function

```
int siteToSiteIdx(int x, int y, int z)  {
    return (x + L) % L + L * ((y + L) % L) + L * L * ((z + L) % L);
}
```

The modulo operator imposes periodic boundary conditions, and the additional $x \rightarrow x + L$ shift is because the modulo operator in C++ doesn't work the way we want it to for negative integers (here I am assuming that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are never less than $-L$, so that a single shift is sufficient).

To get the site index shifted by $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$, we can use the function

```
int translateSiteIdx(int siteIdx, int deltax, int deltay, int deltaz) {
  return siteToSiteIdx((siteIdx % L + deltax + L) % L, ((siteIdx / L) % L + deltay + L) % L, ((siteIdx / (L * L)) + deltaz + L) % L);
};
```

Basically you work backwards to extract the original $x$, $y$ and $z$ indices, apply a shift, and get the new index. I'm having a hard time thinking of a way this could possibly be improved, but this does get called a lot in my code and is actually showing up in profiling as taking up about ~25% of the execution time, so I figured it is worth checking whether I'm doing something dumb or if I've maxed out all I can do. Thanks!

Comment: How big is your stencil? If it has a moderate size and you have no memory restrictions, you could try using buffer/ghost cells at the ends of the domain which simply contain the values from "the other side". That would allow you to avoid the modulo operator since then you are always within the case $x, y, z \leq \tilde L$.

Comment: The other option except for what Dan mentioned (which would require copying ghost values e.g. between matrix-vector mults if those require this retrieval) is to write specialized code paths for interior pixels, 1 off boundary, 2 off boundary etc. I remember even seeing a presentation about experimental domain specific languages that are meant to do this automatically. Dan's approach would however probably also help with memory reads, since the memory will be close by with the ghost cells approach, you pay for this by having to copy in the information though, so idk which is faster for you.

Comment: The best optimization is to just not call a function at all. I would start by looking at where the function is called. Perhaps you are calling it multiple times in the same place, where one could get away with calling it only once and storing the result, or updating the result based on how the arguments to the function change from one place to another.